# C# Low Latency communication between client and host app over the internet

Tags: c#, azure, hex, streamwriter, low-latency

I have created a client and host app which currently send hexadecimal data bidirectionally between them over a Microsoft Azure Relay(using StreamWriter & StreamReader). I have found that I get latencies of about 200-300ms, however when from the host pc I ping the azure relay server, or the client pc I get latencies of about 25ms. My question is does anyone know of a better way of communicating between the client and host apps? I thought maybe WCF, or using a peer to peer communication method.
Thank you

Comment: Yes, host your Azure resources in a geo-region closer to your clients

Comment: Ping is handled at the ethernet network interface while relay is handled at the application layer.  So ping will always be faster.  After a message gets received by network card it must be forwarded to the application that registers for the message which takes time.  The messages are forwarded using Windows Timers which account for the latency.